# Arithmetic expression not resolving in function call

Tags: java, long-integer, arithmetic-expressions, function-call

I have a function that expects a long value as one of the parameter.

```
void doSomething(long limit, ...) {
//statements
}
```

in the function call I pass the argument as,

```
doSomething(5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, ...);
```

The function never receives the final value `5368709120` of the expression, it instead receives `1073741824`. I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: put it `5L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` (note *L* after 5) to be `long`

Comment: Also, you should avoid magic numbers; instead use a `long` constant, e.g. `private static final long SIZE = 5L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the number `5368709120`. The range of integer is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

Integer overflow is happening there . Resulted value in the parameter (`5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`) crossing the limit of int max value. Convert any of the value to long so that the result will be stored to `long`

```
doSomething(5L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, ...); // look the literal L after 5
```

Comment: Expressions like `5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024L` are *dangerous* since `*` is left associative: you can well have an *integer overflow* in `5 * 1024 * 1024 ... *` *before* reaching `1024L`. Safier way is to mark `5` with `L` suffix: *the following expression is long*

Answer (score 0):

Because your invocation sends an `int`, which is then boxed as a `long` after the operation has been performed as `int`.

The operation performed as `int` will overflow `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`) and return undesired results.

You can cast your operation as `long` like so:

```
doSomething((long)5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, ...);
```

You can also test printing out the values:

```
System.out.println(5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // overflowing
System.out.println((long)5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // casted, not overflowing Long.MAX_VALUE
```

**Output**

```
1073741824
5368709120
```